# Element wise(column wise) multiply a single column sparse tensor with a rectangular tensor(same number of rows)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following code:

```
a = tf.constant([[10],
                 [0],
                 [4]])
s = tf.sparse.from_dense(a)
b = tf.constant([[3, 4],
                 [1, 2],
                 [2, 5]])
# print(tf.multiply(s, b))  # this didn't work either though it works if s is dense
print(s.__mul__(b))
```

I want to multiply a with each column of b getting:

```
[[30, 40],
 [ 0,  0],
 [ 8, 20]]
```

But the above code gives me an error that the sparse tensor cant be broadcasted to make the shapes match.

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: SparseDenseBinaryOpShared broadcasts dense to sparse only; got incompatible shapes: [3,1] vs. [3,2] [Op:SparseDenseCwiseMul]
```

How do I achieve the above efficiently without materializing the sparse tensor a into a dense one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how efficient this is and if it is a viable option for you, but you could try using `tf.TensorArray` with `tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant([[10],
                 [0],
                 [4]])
s = tf.sparse.from_dense(a)
b = tf.constant([[3, 4],
                 [1, 2],
                 [2, 5]])

ta = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
for i in range(len(b)):
  if i == len(b):
    ta = ta.write(ta.size(), tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(s, b[i:])[i])
  else:
    ta = ta.write(ta.size(), tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(s, b[i:i + 1])[i])
print(ta.stack())
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[30 40]
 [ 0  0]
 [ 8 20]], shape=(3, 2), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thanks. That does work well. I am trying to get rid of the extra multiplication with the elements of s in each iteration. Something like ta = ta.write(ta.size(), tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(s[i], b[i:i + 1])[i])   does not work as sparse tensors are not subscriptable. However I could have a thousand 0 between 10 & 4 in a, so then there would be a lot of unnecessary mults. I am going to try my sparse tensor impl. where I store the non-zero indices in another tensor like indices_nz=[0, 2].Then I'll do a gather from a only for the indices in indices_nz. Then do the mat mul as above &  scatter.

Comment: Yes. That will definitely work.

Comment: And thanks, tf.stack()/unstack() is awesome!

Comment: Yeah that's true!